# Creating a substring with a varying number of chars

Tags: string, c++11

```
void findNthRoot(string x) {
  if(x.find("rt:") != string::npos) {
    unsigned position = x.find("rt:");
    double n = position - 1;
    double z = position + 3;
    string str1 = x.substr(n, 1);
    string str2 = x.substr(z, 1);     
  }
}

int main() {
  findNthRoot("2 - 1 + 32rt:43 - 89");
}
```

As part of a calculator program, users can enter nrt:x to represent the nth root of a number x. The code I have written above works perfectly fine, but only if the user inputs a root with a single digit n and a single digit x. So my substrings str1 and str2 in this case would be 2 and 4 respectively. I need the substrings to take the entire number followng rt: and the entire number before rt:. I cannot figure out how to do this. I know this is because I have 1 in x.substr(n, 1) but since the user can enter any number they want, I need to somehow be able to account for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `<cctype>` header you have the function [`std::isdigit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) that tells you if a character is a digit.

That way you can find the length of your substring with a simple loop :

```
void findNthRoot(string x)
{
    size_t position = x.find("rt:");
    if (position != string::npos)
    {       
        size_t length = 1;
        size_t n = position - 1;
        while (n > 0 && std::isdigit(x[n - 1]))
        {
            --n;
            ++length;
        }
        string str1 = x.substr(n, length);

        length = 1;
        size_t z = position + 3;
        while (z < x.size() - 1 && std::isdigit(x[z + length]))
            ++length;
        string str2 = x.substr(z, length); 
    }
}

int main()
{
    findNthRoot("2 - 1 + 32rt:43 - 89");
}
```

Comment: Wow that is awesome thank you. I'm looking over the code you gave me to tweak it now, but in testing str2 was correct - no matter what I wrote after rt: I got that number. However, before rt:, all i'm getting is 3.

Comment: Yeah it's because I forgot to update `length` value inside the loop. Check out my edit in a few seconds.

Comment: Okay great, thanks for the help. Now that you have helped me get here,  I need to pass the values to a different method. From here I need to convert them to int from string. This can be done with sstream correct?

Comment: It is correct. Something like `istringstream iss (str); int i; iss >> i; return i;` Or if you're using C++11, you can use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: Yes I am using C++11. So stoi is a std function that converts strings to ints? or does it have other purposes as well

Comment: Yes, stoi takes a string as parameter and returns an int if no problem arises during the conversion (this case an exception is thrown). You can follow the link in my previous comment for more informations.

Comment: Okay, I took a break and now I'm back and i was trying to fully understand the code you gave me. I get that, using isDigit, you are simply executing the while loop and moving one index to the left and counting the length of the number. But why does isDigit have array of x[n-1]?